# Does anyone know why this problem with math and local storage is occurring?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to create a javascript/HTML game where points can be saved over multiple visits to the site, and the save function is working just fine, but when I turn that into a points variable on the load up of the page, the += operator will not work. Instead of using addition to update the variable, it will just add the number to the end of the variable's value. an example of this would be if you said 100 += 1 so that it would make sense for the output to be 101, but instead, it will be 1001.

I have figured out that it is, in fact, the local storage. If just set the points that I'm trying to display to 0 instead of a past score achieved it works fine. This error could possibly be occurring because I am using free web hosting with repl.it so I am sharing a domain with a lot of other sites. I thought about testing if it would work better with cookies but I have never used cookies so I thought I would check here first before trying to learn them.

```
    var points = 0;
    points += localStorage.points;
    // The below is tied to a save button 
    function saveData() {
      localStorage.points = points;
    }
    /*This is also tied to a button with an amount of one, and this is 
    where errors occur. */
    function addPoints(amount) {
      points += amount;
    }
```

sorry if it's sloppy, I'm kind of new to both javascript and game development. Also, I did, in fact, have a checker to see if local storage was available.

Comment: The result you are getting is due to adding strings together. You need to cast points to a number - something like **points ++ parseInt(points)**

Comment: Because it is saved as a string so when you do += it does string concatination.  Add a `parseInt(...)` to convert the string to an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All data stored in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is a `string` (or `undefined`).

So, instead of doing addition, the `+=` operator will do string concatenation.

Try this: `points += +localStorage.points` or `points += Number(localStorage.points)`

You also have to make sure the initial value is not `undefined`.

The full solution would be:

```
    var points = 0;
    if (localStorage.getItem('points') !== null) { 
       // ^^ Similar to localStorage.points !== undefined
       points += +localStorage.points; // Now points won't be type-casted to string
    }
    function saveData() {
      localStorage.points = points;
    }
    /*This is also tied to a button with an amount of one, and this is 
    where errors occur. */
    function addPoints(amount) {
      points += amount;
    }
```

To understand why that happens run this example:

```js
const p = 0;
const s = '1';
const n = 1;
console.log(`p + s = ${p + s}, ${typeof(p+s)} | p + n = ${p + n}, ${typeof(p+n)} | p + +s = ${p + +s}, ${typeof(p + +s)}`);
```

Answer (score 3):

`localStorage` always stores values as strings. Excerpt from [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

> The keys and the values are always strings (note that, as with objects, integer keys will be automatically converted to strings).

You need to first cast `points` to a number.

```
var points = 0;
points += +localStorage.points; // + casts it to a number
```